# How to get sharepoint to sort list in library by fiscal year, and then month

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

I have a list of files in my library with the naming conventions as follows:

Name:
FY19 October Report 1
FY19 November Report 2
FY19 September Report 3
FY19 August Report 4
FY20 October Report 1
FY20 November Report 2
FY20 September Report 3

What I would like is for it to sort by fiscal year, and then by month.  Our fiscal years run from October through September.  How can I achieve this view/result?  Thanks!

Comment: Are FY and Month in separate columns, or are they in the same column?

Comment: Are you trying to parse the fiscal year and month out of the filename?  If so, you'd probably want to create two different calculated columns, something like `=Left([Title], 4)` then you can sort by your calculated columns.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve your requirements:

- Rename 'Month' part in Report names. It should contain integer(number of the month). For example - rename `FY19 October Report 1` to `02(FY)19 October Report 1`. Create 2 additional calculated fields('Year' and 'Month'). For 'Month' calculated field apply formula to retrieve month part from report name(02). For 'Year' calculated field apply formula to retrieve year part from report name(19). Apply sorting by Year column and then by Month.
- As suggested by Lisa Chen - create a "Date and Time" column, then sort by that "Date and Time" column
- If you need sorting from October to September - Create 2 additional columns - 'Month' and 'Year'. While uploading report - fill in new fields. In month field you can set value '010' in case of 'OCT', '011' in case of 'NOV', '012' in case of 'DEC', '1' in case of 'JAN', etc. Also you can achieve it with calculated fields or with workflow which will parse report name and populate fields for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "Date and Time" column, then sort by that "Date and Time" column:

[image]

Here is an similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/574a36e7-e225-4010-8556-aa08845193f5/need-to-sort-year-then-month-then-date-in-sharepoint-2010-view?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious